# How to solve Flash of Unstyled Text in Angular?

Tags: angular, font-face, google-material-icons

My `custom font` and `material icons` are switched to default font and text respectively when loading any route for the first time. How to eliminate that behavior in `Angular 5 app`?

Comment: This isn't normal behavior, you will need to elaborate and provide a minimal complete and verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Okay, thanks for pointing out. I'm trying to reproduce. On production version it works fine. But on development the problems remains.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else coming across this issue I found that `mat-icon` components were being loaded with my default font that I had set at a higher level in the project (in my case this was Open Sans). Then the icons would appear only after the `Material Icons` font-family finished loading.

I solved the issue by specifically setting the font-family to `Material Icons` on all `mat-icon` elements at a higher level.

```
.mat-icon, mat-icon {
  font-family: 'Material Icons' !important;
}
```

While I generally recommend against using `!important` in CSS - this does seem like a reasonable place to use it as no other font should load these icons except for the `Material Icons` font if you want to prevent the Flash of Unstyled Text.